# xmodmap KeyPress Event to ButtonPress event

Tags: xmodmap

I just got a logitech t400 mouse and everything is working well, except I want to remap the "top" part of the middle mouse to actual middle mouse function.

When I run `xev`, and capture the clicks, all the mouse buttons return a `ButtonPress`/`ButtonRelease` event but the top part of the middle button returns a `KeyPress`/`KeyRelease` event as :

```
KeyPress event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
root 0x31d, subw 0x0, time 630089839, (80,128), root:(2871,588),
state 0x10, keycode 133 (keysym 0x31d, (no name)), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
root 0x31d, subw 0x0, time 630089983, (80,128), root:(2871,588),
state 0x50, keycode 133 (keysym 0x31d, (no name)), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

The bottom part of the middle button works fine, and returns :

```
ButtonPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
root 0x31d, subw 0x0, time 630137726, (10,171), root:(2801,631),
state 0x10, button 2, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
root 0x31d, subw 0x0, time 630138960, (10,171), root:(2801,631),
state 0x210, button 2, same_screen YES
```

I would like the remap the top part the same way as the bottom part, is this possible with xmodmap ?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve tried this as well, and eventually found – buried deep in the docs – that this is not possible.

[This forum post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/simulating-a-mouse-click-594576/) contains C code that uses the `XSendEvent` function to emulate a button press. You could start it using `xbindkeys`, for example.

The forum thread also suggests to use [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/). Disclaimer: I’ve not tried it yet.